# Effects of low frequency in a genset

Tags: power-supply, power, ac, power-electronics, generator

I am working in a oversized genset that has 150 kW - 180 kVA capacity but it just has a demand of 20 kW, for this reason the control system try to maintain engine velocity but as the load is so low it is continuously oscillating between 1600 - 1900 rpm while it is designed to operate at 1800 rpm. This oscillation affect directly the frequency of the operator so, what kind of disadvantages to the grid will carry this instability in motor speed.

Here it is a graph of the RPM behavior.

[image]

Comment: TFM, is that you?

Comment: Is this really a grid fed by multiple generators or a single generator feeding a distribution network with multiple loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as the load is so low it is continuously oscillating between 1600 - 1900 rpm

I doubt very much that the cause is the load being low. It appears that there is a major, short-time perturbation every so often. It seems more likely that the cause is a larger load that is switched on occasionally. You should look to see how much voltage variation occurs at those times. You should also look at the perturbation on a shorter time scale to see what the spikes look like over the duration of the perturbation. The effect on other loads would depend on the characteristics of each of the other loads. Many loads would probably not be much affected.

Comment: but as the generator is designed to operate at 1800 rpm because has 4 poles and need 60 hz output. this pikes and low rpm are affecting the frequency?

Comment: Yes, the frequency or the waveform will be affected.

Comment: but think that for example the load is ridiculous low, for example 10% of capacity. this low load could also cause that variation? I mean if for example right now the the Generator is in a 10 % load but suddenly as you say one bigger load, as we have here(electric engines) demand more power to the primary engine but as this primary engine was not loaded so the fuel injection isn't big, this new charge will need a sudden response in the primary engine, so what will happen is a suddenly acceleration and when this happens a peak is reached but as the peak is reached the control tries to slow...

Comment: A sudden substantial load increase or decrease will certainly cause some transient response in the generator. The magnitude and duration of the response will depend on the magnitude and rate of change of the load as well as the inertia of the system, the design of the regulating system and the machine characteristics. The size of the base load will have something to do with the response, but the cause is the load change, not the magnitude of the base load.